# Java - A loop in a loop and the format gets lost

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm French so excuse my English not necessarily correct.

I explain the context, I currently have a String array list named "tempCustomerDrugsIdsList" (var1) and another string array list named "tempDrugsTableList"(var2).

When I make a loop "For" on "var1" then another one in "var2","var2" loses its format, i. e. upper case is replaced by lower case and spaces are deleted.

I tested with another loop with the same type of variables (but empty), the result being the same I think the problem comes from my way of using java. Being on vb. net before, I must have taken some bad habits !

I don't know how to solve this problem, I've only been working in java for 2 weeks.

Thank you for helping me.

[EDIT]

My problem was:

```
List<String[]> tempDrugsTableList = otherList;
```

But this code doesn't duplicate the list.

AxelH gave me the following solution:

```
List<String[]> tempDrugsTableList = new ArrayList<String[]>(otherList);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve your chances of getting an answer by trying to improve based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve], I doubt (i know it can't) the iteration of a `List<String[]>` could do any changes in a `String` (well, a `String` is immutable socreate a new instance with some update) so unless you show use something with that behavior, I doubt you will find an answer. **How do you add those arrays ?, this is where you have a problem, the inital array are not what you think**

Comment: Please provide example input and a corresponding expected output.

Comment: I put my two variables as well as an output example.

Comment: I see a `CsvReader`, I see a `ResultDB`, ... where is the reproducible part in this ?? Read how to create a  [mcve], we can help with this ... I would guess for now that the problem is in your data (either the CSV or the DB), but I can't check the code if I don't have values. Use constant array to create an example please

Comment: My apologies, I misspoke. Before entering the first loop, I get good results, but as soon as I enter the second loop (tempDrugsTableList(var2)), the whole format is changed.
The _CsvReader recovers in UTF-8 and the resultDb too.

Comment: That my last comment, I will not try much longer ... I don't see any [mcve] (for the thirst times), your loops just iterate a collection/array and print them, they don't do any update. Since the reader and the db are not a problem, why are you even adding them here ? Clean the question, provide a short and reproducible (only constant value) code that would let us see and test the problem. Explain what you are trying to do (why to loop on `tempDrugsTableList` ? ) Until this, good luck.

Comment: `tmpBrandName.replaceAll("\\s", "");` means remove the spaces ...

Comment: Are you serious? They ask me to put the code and I put it then I specify that before entering the second loop I have the correct format BUT when entering the second one (so when you get the iterations of tempDrugsTableList) there the format changes and I have no spaces or capital letters!

And now you're asking me to put code that is not used for resolution (I think) and you're annoyed that I don't put it...

Comment: My question is simple, why when I enter this variable with a "for"loop, the iterations lose their format (spaces and uppercase) while in the first one the format is kept?

I thank you for your attention to my problem, which is why I do not want us to be on bad terms for a misunderstanding.

Comment: tmpBrandName is a separate variable that tells me whether or not the drug name has already been added, it is not returned. As a precaution I removed this instruction and the one modifying the string but nothing does.

Comment: Nobody asked you the code, we asked for a short and reproducible example and an explanation of what you want and what you currently have. So my answer to your _simple question_ is that simple, it can't be. The loops your shows use only print the content of two distinct list without any logic, so they will be identical before and after the loops.

Comment: That's the point! I don't understand why it won't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not doing a "copy" of the list

```
tempDrugsTableListCopy = tempDrugsTableList; // Get copy of original tempDrugsTableList for comparate
```

but sharing the reference, every update done in the `tempDrugsTableListCopy` will be done in the original list (same reference, same adress in memory). Since you are updating that copy in the following loops ... you update the original list too. What you want is to clone the list.

You could do it simply with `copyList = new ArrayList(originalList);` or for a deep clone, you need to iterate each element to duplicate those. (array need to be duplicated too if you change the value in those)

Comment: I just posted the "real problem" I didn't have permission to show this code (yes, French companies are stuck with sharing) but I think I'm having problems with my way of doing things as I said.
I'm sorry to have done all this brainstorming, I misunderstood everything and didn't explain the problem correctly! Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: @NathanMeynaud see the edit. And not having the permission to show a code is one of the reason we ask for a [mcve], this should be a new code, out of any context focusing one the problem. (trust me, I work in Luxembourg, I know what is the secrecy ...)

Comment: Thank you very much, I can only admire you. Anyway, my secret code is completely at the level of a beginner... it's the company that works like this. I thank you for enlightening me on my problem, it came from my way of doing things.

Comment: @NathanMeynaud next time, just provide a small and similar code (no need of that many line), dividing a code in small block would give you a more specific location on the problem, allowing to debug easily), next time, you might not have the help you desire with a question like this ... Good luck for the rest.

Comment: thank you, I remember and saw the size of the method I was starting to think that it should be separated.

Answer (score -1):

"String[]" tmpCustomerIds means you are getting a string array from a string array, which you would be using in a 2d array. Try it with just "String" in the for each loops. I am assuming you are using 1d arrays in this case.

Comment: It would not compile if it was the case, the loop know the type it should get. It is a "_String array list named "tempCustomerDrugsIdsList"_" so I guess `List<String[]>`

Comment: Yes, i use 2d arrays, not 1d.